# closed form expression for an infinite series

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, power-series, hypergeometric-functions

Is there any closed form expression for the infinite sum $\sum_{n \geq 0}q^{n(n+1)/2}(1+q)(1+q^2)\cdots(1+q^n)u^n$ where both $q$ and $n$ are variables and $n \in N \cup {0}$?

Comment: Since the coefficient of $u^n$ is a polynomial in $q$ of degree, roughly, $n^2$, there should be no closed form expression that is a rational function.  Since the coefficients of $u^n$ satisfy a linear recurrence, the $q$-degrees would have to grow linearly in $n$.  Maybe it could have a closed expression that is a rational function in $u$, but the coefficients are not all polynomials in $q$.

Comment: Didn't you rather mean $q^{-n(n+1)/2}$ ?

Comment: @Lucian:  Of course I have no idea what the OP meant, but I thought that I would mention that my comment is still valid if the factor is $q^{-n(n+1)/2}$.  After a change of variables $s=1/q$, my comment shows that the expression cannot be a rational function in $s$ and $u$.  But every rational function in $q$ and $u$ is also a rational function in $s$ and $u$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Sorry for the confusion, my comment was addressed at the OP.

Comment: @Lucian no its $q^{n(n+1)/2}$

Comment: What does this have to do with lie groups and lie algebras?

Comment: Are there nontrivial special cases you can do?  Say, $u=1$?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar no i can not do when u =1,but when q =1,it is just $1/(1-2u)$

Comment: @RichardRast it comes out to be generating function of multiplicities of Demazure modules in a Demazure flag of weyl module.

Comment: It looks like some basic hypergeometric function!